# LL grammar and FIRST

Tags: ll-grammar

Suppose a chunk of LL grammar

```
STATEMENT ::= ε | R
R         :: = print (variable)
```

And I try to find the FIRST(Statement)

```
FIRST(STATEMENT) = FIRST(ε) + FIRST(R)
FIRST(R) = { print (variable) }
```

My question is. Is the FIRST(R) correct ? Or the below:

```
FIRST(R) = {print}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, FIRST(R) is just `print`, assuming that `print` is a token.

Comment: Thank you for you answer !! Hmmm !!! So, must we split the right side to tokens in order to run FIRST algorithm ?

Comment: You have to split the right side in terminals and non-terminals. Then you can apply the [rules](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cs415/reading/FirstFollowLL.pdf)

Comment: Hmmm !! So, does the "print (variable)" consist of two non-terminals ?

Comment: I don't know, it depends on the grammar. Anyway I think that print, ( and ) are terminals. `variable` is a terminal too if it does not appear as left side on any production rule.